# Gráfico de colunas empilhadas no R

Tags: r

Tenho uma base de dados em que as variáveis assumem valores inteiros de 1 a 5.

Segue uma base exemplo com as variáveis `X1`, `X2` e `X3`:

```
base<- rbind(
c(5,3,3),c(4,3,2),c(4,5,4),c(1,5,1),c(1,2,1),c(3,4,2),
c(2,3,2),c(3,1,3),c(3,2,4),c(5,1,5),c(3,4,5),c(5,4,4),
c(2,3,3),c(1,2,3),c(3,4,2),c(1,5,1),c(1,3,2),c(3,4,3),
c(4,2,3),c(4,2,3),c(1,3,3),c(1,3,4),c(1,2,2))  
base = data.frame(base)
```

Por favor como fazer um gráfico de colunas empilhadas com as frequências de ocorrência desses valores? Ou seja, seria um gráfico com três colunas (X1, X2, X3) e cada coluna teria 5 divisões proporcionais à frequência de cada um desses valores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você reformatar sua base de dados é fácil fazer com o `ggplot2`. Para reformatar vou usar o `reshape2` e `dplyr`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
molten <- melt(base, variable.name = "variavel", value.name = "valores")
df <- molten %>% 
  group_by(variavel, valores = factor(valores)) %>% 
  summarise(frequencia = n())

ggplot(df, aes(x = variavel, y = frequencia, fill = valores)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Desde o `ggplot2 2.2.0` há também também o [`geom_col()`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html) que é um atalho para `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`.

Neste caso, a sintaxe para o gráfico usando o `df` do @Cinelli seria:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = variavel, y = frequencia, fill = valores)) +
  geom_col()
```